# AJAX Headers (Firefox vs Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I have come across an interesting situation involving AJAX calls, and wondering if anyone could offer some sort of explanation.

```
1. $.ajax({
2.     type: "POST",
3.     headers: {
4.     "Content-Type": "application/json"
5.     "authToken": //auth token
6. },
7.     url: "/api",
8.     data: JSON.stringify(dataFormValues)
9. })
10. .done(function(data) {
11.     //do the next thing
12. })
13. .error(function(data) {
14.     //show error message
15. });
```

This works well, until we tested in Firefox. Apparently this will not work in Firefox without line 4 being modified to:

```
....
4. "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
....
```

Then once moving to testing in Internet Explorer (IE 11), I noticed that it doesn't even really care what the header is; with or without the utf-8 in the header it makes the call perfectly fine.

Is anyone aware of Firefox vs Chrome's UTF-8 header restrictions?

Comment: When you say it "will not work", what exactly do you mean? What fails and how? What does the outgoing HTTP request look like as shown from the browser network console?

Comment: I mean that the request fails, and an error is thrown. This is not an error from any API

Comment: What exactly is this error? What throws it?