# JQuery Post throw fail despite success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, firefox

I run a `$.post` request in jQuery to a server, the php code runs correctly but in firefox the post request throw a error and jump in the `.fail` function. in chrome it works perfect but in firefox not.

```js
$.post(url, {
    products: JSON.stringify(tempArray)
  },
  function(data) {

  }).done(function() {

  sendingCount++;

}).fail(function() {
  alert("error");
});
```

why call firefox a error and chrome not ? and data works completely on the server site

Comment: Open developer console or firebug and inspect response from ajax request.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34339938/863110) question will help you.

Comment: Can you try to explicit the content-type to application/json both on the ajax call as well as on the header of your php?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the below:

```
var products = JSON.stringify(tempArray);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: {"products": products}
}).success(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
 console.log(data);
 sendingCount++;
}).fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
 console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

When developing a jQuery AJAX JavaScript script use the Firefox [network monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) or the Chrome [network panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/#network) to gain insight into XHR requests and the server response.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

I have changed the post function to the ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    },
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(tempArray)
}).done(function(data){
    console.log('success');
}).error(function(data){
    console.log('error');
});
```